# How do I invoke a callback in a unit test in Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, viewmodel

I want to invoke a callback to assert the execution it makes.

I'm using MVVM in my app. In one of the view models I implemented, I want to make sure the ui state changes when a process is completed.

In my `HomeViewModel.kt` I have:

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel
@Inject
constructor(
    private val storageRepository: StorageRepository,
    private val accountRepository: AccountRepository,
) : ViewModel() {
// First state of isLoading is true
var uiState = mutableStateOf(HomeUiState())

...

fun addListener() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        storageRepository.addListener(
            accountRepository.getUserId(),
            ::onDocumentEvent,
            onComplete = { 
                uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(isLoading = false) 
            },
            onError = { 
                error -> onAddListenerFailure(error) 
            }
        )
    }
}
```

And I want to write the test:

**Given** homeViewModel.addListener()

**When** storageRepository.addListener(...) completes

**Then** uiState.isLoading is false

I've been searching for some time now and I have found some people referring to using captors from mockito but nothing that applies to my case.

This is what I have now

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
internal class HomeViewModelTest {
  // mock repositories
  @Mock lateinit var storageRepository: StorageRepository
  @Mock lateinit var accountRepository: AccountRepository
  @Mock lateinit var logRepository: LogRepository

  // set dispatcher to be able to run tests
  private val dispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()

  lateinit var callbackCaptor: KArgumentCaptor<() -> Unit>

  @Before
  fun setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)
    Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
  }

  @After
  fun tearDown() {
    Dispatchers.resetMain()
  }

  @Test
  fun `loading state is true when viewModel is created`() {
    val homeViewModel = HomeViewModel(storageRepository, accountRepository, logRepository)
    assertTrue(homeViewModel.uiState.value.isLoading)
  }

  @Test
  fun `loading state is false when listener is added successfully`() {
    val homeViewModel = HomeViewModel(storageRepository, accountRepository, logRepository)
    callbackCaptor = argumentCaptor()

    whenever(
        storageRepository.addListener(
          anyString(),
          anyOrNull(),
          callbackCaptor.capture(),
          anyOrNull()
        )
      )
      .thenAnswer { callbackCaptor.firstValue.invoke() }

    homeViewModel.addListener()

    // wait for mutable state to update
    dispatcher.scheduler.advanceUntilIdle()
    assertFalse(homeViewModel.uiState.value.isLoading)
  }
}
```

Of course, I'm open to hearing solutions using something else than captors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not initialising the captor, try following

```
@Test
fun `loading state is false when listener completes its process`() {
    val homeViewModel = HomeViewModel(storageRepository, accountRepository, logRepository)

val callbackCaptor = argumentCaptor<() -> Unit>() //used kotlin mockito

    whenever(storageRepository.addListener(anyString(), any(), callbackCaptor.capture(), any()))
        .thenAnswer { callbackCaptor.firstValue.invoke() } 

    homeViewModel.addListener()

    // wait for mutable state to update
    dispatcher.scheduler.advanceUntilIdle()

    assertFalse(homeViewModel.uiState.value.isLoading)
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sylwek854 for your answer. Sadly this didn't work either. I'm not getting the `callbackCaptor.capture() must not be null` error anymore but the test is failing. Now I'm not even sure if the use of the captor here is proper... I'm going to edit the question with your callout. Thank you again and if you have a sample where you execute a callback that you can share that'd be awesome.